# Where to get SymbolMT and how to use it once obtained?

Tags: fonts, symbols, ghostscript, dvips, mapping

Upon launching `dvips` or `dvipdf` on a certain DVI file generated today with a standard `latex`-`bibtex` loop from the current Debian-stable TeX Live, I get

> dvips: Font SymbolMT used in file some_diagram.eps is not in the mapping file.

Viewing the old EPS file and the resulting PS file with `gv` and the resulting PDF file with `evince`, I see boxes at certain places instead of meaningful glyphs. (Oposed to this, a prior version of the PDF and PS files, compiled on Jul 20, 2023 CEST, probably also using packages from TeX Live in Debian stable, does have proper glyphs.)

In the compiled .tex file, we discover

```latex
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{some_diagram.eps}
```

Further:

```bash
$ grep -C5 SymbolMT some_diagram.eps 
F /F1 0 /0 F /TTFF4D68D8t00 mF 
/F1S96 F1 [150 0 0 -150 0 0 ] mFS
F1S96 Ji 
1804 1960 M <01020304>[97 75 76  0]xS 

%%IncludeResource: font SymbolMT
F /F2 0 /2 F /SymbolMT mF 
/F2S96 F2 [150 0 0 -150 0 0 ] mFS
F2S96 Ji 
2082 1960 M <D9>S 
F1S96 Ji 
2207 1960 M <01>S 
--
LH
%%PageTrailer

%%Trailer
%%DocumentNeededResources: 
%%+ font SymbolMT
%%DocumentSuppliedResources: 
%%+ procset Pscript_WinNT_ErrorHandler 5.0 0
%%+ procset Pscript_FatalError 5.0 0
%%+ procset Pscript_Win_Basic 5.0 0
%%+ procset Pscript_Win_Utils_L2 5.0 0
$ head -14 some_diagram.eps 
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Title: Microsoft PowerPoint - some_diagram
%%Creator: PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2
%%CreationDate: 2/21/2009 0:17:58
%%BoundingBox: 6 8 784 606
%%Pages: 1
%%Orientation: Landscape
%%PageOrder: Ascend
%%DocumentNeededResources: (atend)
%%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%TargetDevice: (HP LaserJet 9050 mfp) (3010.107) 0
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%EndComments
$ tlmgr search SymbolMT # using tlmgr from the current TeX Live 2023
$ grep -a SymbolMT /path_to_a_Windows_partiton/Windows/Fonts/symbol.ttf
… Symbol :version 1.70 (Microsoft)Version 5.01SymbolMTMonotype TypographyMonotype …
$ ls -la /usr/local/share/fonts/Windows_Fonts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff 28 21. Jan 02:03 /usr/local/share/fonts/Windows_Fonts -> /path_to_a_Windows_partiton/Windows/Fonts
```

A search on CTAN for SymbolMT leads nowhere. Any idea on how to get meaningful glyphs into the output without redrawing the visual contents of some_diagram.eps? (To this end, is, perhaps, any package of TeX Live to be installed or upgraded?)

Comment: MonoType Symbol which is I think the same as the Microsoft Windows system installed Symbol font.

Comment: https://www.myfonts.com/collections/symbol-font-microsoft-corporation (paid)

Comment: https://catalog.monotype.com/font/microsoft-corporation/symbol/regular

Comment: as you actually show in your question the symbol.ttf you have in Windows/Fonts has SymbolMT as its internal font name

Comment: General info: The "font name" is usually not the same as the "font file name". The file name is what you see in a list of files. The font name is internal to the font, and is what you see when you view the font in a font viewer application. They may or may not be similar names. Also, when you see a font with "MT" in the font name,, its usage may be restricted to certain purposes, because it is not a "libre" free font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `gnome-font-viewer /path_to_a_Windows_partiton/Windows/Fonts/symbol.ttf` shows “Symbol“ as the name and “Regular” as the style (both in Greek and in Latin letters). The string “SymbolMT”, on the contrary, is NOT shown; this string is only known to occur as a substring of the file contents; this may or may not be relevant. As for “MT”, someone on the WWW wrote that it means “MonoType”. Anyhow, do you think this file is relevant? There might already be a font file advertising itself with the name SymbolMT somewhere in TeXLive; I only could not find it so far.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've just looked up references on how to make a ttf file usable in LaTeX; such changes are unlikely to survive the upgrades of TeX Live :-(. Something changed in TeX Live recently for the worse in this specific regard.

Comment: it won't be in texlive it's monotype (MT) implementation of the PostScript Symbol font If I look in c:\windows\fonts\symbol.ttf in fontforge I [see this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIBob.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed, fontforge reports the same data for my symbol.ttf as for yours. SymbolMT is the font name also here.